How should we name our chat room?
Stack exchange sites have chatrooms. Chatrooms have names, usually funny.
What should ours be called?

I propose that it's called Bar Sport because:

it is an eponymous example of "idle chatter" (non siamo al bar sport)
it is a very Italian thing, probably only Italians will "get it"
it is self-deprecating
it reminds me of a funny book
it is an Italian phrase ...in English


+1 I never used the chat on SE but the name is very auto-ironic and appropriate.

+1, I never used the chat on SE but the name is very auto-ironic and appropriate.

I wasn't convinced, but the last point ("it is an Italian phrase ...in English") did.

I agree, good suggestion. Where's the chat room anyway? Sorry, I've never used it but would like to start.

It is here: [chat]

@Sklivvz You should accept your own answer at this point ;)
